# What tenses can we use aside the simple present in clauses introduced by when, as soon as, the minute etc.?

Tags: grammar, tense

I know we can use the simple present in those clause, with a potential (irrealis) meaning, but is there any other tense we can use?

ex:

> Text me when you get there.

What other tenses can we use after "when"? And why?

Comment: When you have got there. When you're about to get there. Is "about to" a tense? I don't know. Some people have a strange idea of what are tenses in English: some claim, for example, that the modal form with "will" is a tense though it is syntactically indistinguishable from other modals like "may" and "could".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present perfect works perfectly. This expresses the reality that by the time you tell me, you will have been there for at least a small amount of time.

> Tell me when you have gotten there.
>   Tell me as soon as you have gotten there.
>   Tell me the minute you have gotten there.

You could use the simple past tense if the context is set in the past already.

> I wanted you to tell when you got there.
>   I wanted you to tell me as soon as you got there.
>   I wanted you to tell me the minute you got there.

or the past perfect as in my first example, but when speaking about the past

> I wanted you to tell when you had gotten there.
>   I wanted you to tell me as soon as you had gotten there.
>   I wanted you to tell me the minute you had gotten there.